# Arduino клавиатура не найдена

Tags: arduino

Первый раз работаю с ардуино.

Суть в том, что бы при нажатии кнопки печатался текст

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

#include <Mouse.h>

void setup() {
  pinMode(1,INPUT_PULLUP);
Keyboard.begin();

}

void loop() {
  // read the pushbutton:
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // if the button state has changed,
  if ((buttonState != previousButtonState)
      // and it's currently pressed:
      && (buttonState == HIGH)) {
    // increment the button counter
    counter++;
    // type out a message
    Keyboard.print("You pressed the button ");

  }
  // save the current button state for comparison next time:
  previousButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

при компиляции выдает ошибку  `Клавиатура не найдена. Убедитесь входит ли скетч в код  #include <Keyboard.h>`

Указывает на строку `Keyboard.print("You pressed the button ");`

Comment: Я обычно отлаживаю другим способом, использую Serial.

Comment: Код будет работать на платах Arduion Leonardo и аналогичных (которые умеют "прикидываться" USB HID устройством). Если у вас Arduino Uno, например, то работать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, тип платы указан неверно. Этот код будет работать только на процессоре ATmega32u4.

Comment: Дело в том что у меня компьютер вообще не видит данное устройство, светодиоды мигают но на этом все заканчивается